# Wallis Product with integrals

Tags: integration, inequality, definite-integrals

> Prove, for  every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, that
>
> a) (done) $\displaystyle\int_0
> ^{\pi/2} \sin^nx\,dx=\frac{n-1}{n}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{n-2}x\,dx$, $n\geq2$.
>
> b) $\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{2n+2}x\,dx\leq\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{2n+1}x\,dx\leq\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{2n}x\,dx.$

So, using part (a)

$$\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{2n+2}x\,dx =\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2n}x\,dx\leq\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2n}x\,dx$$

But I don't know how do reduce the expoent in only one unit, since part (a) reduces two units per once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two parts are in fact not related: the second is actually about the form of the integrand.

We have $ 0 < \sin x < 1 $ for each $x \in (0,\pi/2) $. By the first inequality, multiplication by $\sin x$ preserves inequalities, so
$$ 0 < \sin^{n+1} x < \sin^n x $$
for any $n$. Since integration also preserves strict inequalities, we then have
$$ 0 < \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{n+1} x \, dx < \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^n x \, dx , $$
from which the required inequalities follows.

Answer (score 0):

This is much simpler than what you're trying to do: the inequalities are satisfied because on the interval $\bigl[0,\frac\pi 2\bigr]$, one has $0\le\sin x\le  1$, and if $0\le y\le 1$,
$$y^{\alpha}  \le y^{\beta}\quad\text{ if }\; \alpha\ge \beta,$$
whence the inequalities for the integrals.